# Can not get session value after creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

My controller is:

```
  def index
     puts session.inspect
   end

  def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @asset.save
        unless session[:assets] && session[:assets].kind_of?(Array)
          session[:assets] = Array.new
        end
        session[:expires_at] = Time.now + 1.hour
        session[:assets] << @asset  
      end
  end
```

I want to save some models into session and get later, But After create some assets, I can not get anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store them here, use a relashionship. For example, in user, `has_many :assets`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to store complex object(Asset) inside of session - unfortunately this will not work. What you want to do is save unique key in session and retrieve objects from database on next load:

`session[:assets] << @asset.id`

In index you can call:

`puts Asset.where(:id => session[:assets]).all.inspect`